# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

first sorry if my english isn't good enough XD. Second, I'm programing on ASP.NET Core 2.0. And when i launch my webapp i get the next error when i try  to go to the "Clases" web page of my App.

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'EduCloud.Data.IClassInfo' while attempting to activate 'EduCloud.Controllers.UnitsController'.

Before all, sorry if it is too much code. The code for the Model involve is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace EduCloud.Data.Models
{
    public class ClassInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ClassVideoUrl { get; set; }
        public string ClassHomeworkUrl { get; set; }
        public string TestUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual Forum Forum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This Model has 1 level of abstraction with the class**

```
using EduCloud.Data.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EduCloud.Data
{
    public interface IClassInfo
    {
        ClassInfo GetById(int id);
        IEnumerable<ClassInfo> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<ClassInfo> GetFilteredClasses(Forum forum, string searchQuery);
        IEnumerable<ClassInfo> GetFilteredClasses(string searchQuery);
        IEnumerable<ClassInfo> GetClassesByForum(int id);

        Task Add(ClassInfo classInfo);
        Task Delete(int id);
        Task EditClassContent(int id, string newContent);
    }
}
```

Next, the methods of the this IClass are in the next class

```
using EduCloud.Data;
using EduCloud.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EduCloud.Service
{
    public class ApplicationClassService : IUnit
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ApplicationClassService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task Create(ClassInfo classInfo)
        {
            _context.Add(classInfo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public Task Delete(int classId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Forum> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Forums
                .Include(forum => forum.Classes);
        }

        public Forum GetById(int id)
        {
            var forum = _context.Forums.Where(f => f.Id == id)
                .Include(f => f.Classes ).ThenInclude(p => p.User)
                //.Include(f => f.Classes).ThenInclude(p => p.Replies).ThenInclude(r => r.User)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return forum;
        }

        public Task UpdateForumTitle(int classId, string newTitle)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally the Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EduCloud.Data;
using EduCloud.Data.Models;
using EduCloud.Models.Classes;
using EduCloud.Models.Units;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace EduCloud.Controllers
{
    public class UnitsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnit _unitService;
        private readonly IForum _forumService;
        private readonly IClassInfo _classService;

        public UnitsController(IUnit unitService, IForum forumService, IClassInfo classService)
        {
            _unitService = unitService;
            _forumService = forumService;
            _classService = classService;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var units = _unitService.GetAll()
                .Select(forum => new UnitsListingModel
                {
                    Id = forum.Id,
                    Name = forum.Title,
                });

            var model = new UnitsIndexModel
            {
                UnitList = units
            };

            return View(model);

        }

    }
}
```

And the code of the view that i try to run when i go to the "Clases" link

```
@model EduCloud.Models.Units.UnitsIndexModel

<h1>Unidades de Aprendizaje</h1>

<table class="table table-hover" id="forumIndexTable">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forum in Model.UnitList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="Units" asp-action="ClassesList" asp-route-id="@forum.Id">
                        @forum.Name
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you registered implementation of  `IClassInfo` in the DI? Also in the provided code there is no implemetation of `IClassInfo`.

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver, i don´t know how to thank you enough. I was a really simple error, but i completely overlooked it. it's been two days for me trying to solve it, and it is an assignment of a class that i have to lend next tuesday. Again, thank you bro, really thank you.

Comment: Was glad to help!